# Assigning a property of an object using another object property calls an error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

The problem I ran into in the project can be simplified as below:

```
const obj1 = {
  name: 'bob',
  age: 18
}

const obj2 = {
  name: 'tom',
  age: 19
}
for (const key in obj1) {
  obj1[key] = obj2[key]
}
for (const key in obj1) {
  type Key = keyof typeof obj1
  obj1[key as Key] = obj2[key as Key]
}
for (const key in obj1) {
  type Key = keyof typeof obj1
  type Value = typeof obj1[Key]
  (obj1[key as Key] as Value) = obj2[key as Key]
}
```

The first `for` said `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; age: number; }'`.I totally understand, so I tried the second `for`.

The second `for` said `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`, which made me very confused.

Though I managed using the third `for`, I still can't understand why Typescript displayed this error: `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`

The whole code can be found at this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAjDAvDA3gWAFAxjAEMBbAUwC4YByAMyLGoBo8CiBzSmZADjwF88eUJFgJEAJnRZWhUlzoMJzWRy7IAnALy0QAJxgAKEdBgBrMgE8YASzBwkyAJQz8DlAG0LlgLrTxEl5WPtq4ugbG4Kbetvbizq4EUJYADmQwANJW0t4gtDDJaXnuyLLxQdZEEJnB-kiBMVU1vqHhRiawMXYlLjhuhelZ1hi5+QPF8bIDMABqRAA2AK7pGOP55UMhbobljdWbME1zS2QuGAEVh-vBoXhAA)

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not declare the types properly for `obj1` and `obj2` so typescript is inferring types as never

```
const obj1:Record<string,string|number>= {
  name: 'fan',
  age: 18
}

const obj2:Record<string,string|number>= {
  name: 'fan2',
  age: 19
}
for (const key in obj1) {
  obj1[key] = obj2[key]
}
```

even the first syntax wont throw any error if we declare the types for the objects

[playground_link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAjALgEoFNQCcAmAPNDgJZgDmANMWeQD5gCuAtvJjgHwC8MA3gLAAoGDDABDZplQwA5ADMxYGZSEix5KTGQAOIQF8hQ0JFgJEAJgzYQ%20IlFIVq92gxZtOPAcNETN8xebKqjDqmsgAnPpCcjYwABTG0DAA1pgAnjBkcEjIAJR8wWbIANqpaQC6MDxm5qXp5VGCMTjxibBlmWDZKPleIlBpAA6YMADS6VUp6SByMAPDM93IhTl1GWIQY-WTNWshm%20MVjc2t4EkdWUW9wfMjh5Nli7eLRTdDIwBqYgA2jCM8z1mRWKhwa3jiwI6Gy2FX2MC%20v0w%20WqSFqUIO9UaQiAA)

Comment: Well, this is a workaround. But I think this method will lose the information of the Object keys.Though I create an `interface IObj {name: string; age: number}`, It will still raise the same error.